# How to copy data

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to create a stored procedure that copy data from 3 tables. These are the structure of the 3 tables:

```
Quotes
Quote_id integer, note varchar(50)
```

Quote_id is a primary key and auto incremented using a trigger

```
Windows
Win_id integer, quote_id integer
```

Win_id is a primary key (auto incremented using a trigger) and Quote_id here is a FK to quotes table

```
Win_links
Links_id integer, win_id integer, linked_win_id integer, edge_name varchar(30)
```

Links_id is primary key (auto incremented using a trigger) and both win_id and linked_win_id are FK to windows table.

I created the SP like this:

```
create or alter procedure COPY_QUOTE_PROC (
    P_QUOTE_ID integer)
As
declare variable V_LAST_INSERTED_QUOTE_ID integer;
declare variable V_OLD_WIN_ID integer;
begin
  insert into quotes (note) select note from quotes where quotes.quote_id = :P_QUOTE_ID
returning QUOTE_ID into :v_last_inserted_quote_id;

FOR select WIN_ID from windows
  where (windows.quote_id = :p_quote_id)
    into :V_OLD_WIN_ID
  do begin
    insert into windows (quote_id) select :v_last_inserted_quote_id from windows where WIN_ID = :v_old_win_id
end
```

The third table used to link windows within one quote together for example win_id = 5 and linked_win_id = 6 another record may have same window but linked to different window for example win_id = 5 and linked_win_id = 7  and so on.

Now how I also copy the third table `win_links` so it point correctly to newly copied windows ?

Comment: You probable need a global temporary table that maintains a mapping of the old and new ids to be able to pull this off.

Comment: Yes Mark I already did something like that.